# Custom button in product form does not generate a proper form key

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent, custom-button

So I need to add a Save & Close button on the product grid.
[image: like that]
It even works, but not quite so. On clicking that button product is saved, and redirect to product grid happens. But with an error "Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.": 
[image: like that].
In page code, I see that form keys on the back button and Save & Close button are different.

Button is added via product_form.xml :

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="save-close-button" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Save</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
```

Button class:

```
class Save extends Generic
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        if ($this->getProduct()->isReadonly()) {
            return [];
        }

        return [
            'id_hard' => 'save_and_close_add',
            'label' => __('Save & Close'),
            'class' => 'save',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'buttonAdapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => $this->getSaveTarget(),
                                'actionName' => $this->getSaveAction(),
                                'params' => [
                                    true
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'class_name' => Container::DEFAULT_CONTROL,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve target for button.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getSaveTarget()
    {
        $target = 'product_form.product_form';
        if ($this->isConfigurableProduct()) {
            $target = 'product_form.product_form.configurableVariations';
        }
        return $target;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve action for button.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getSaveAction()
    {
        $action = 'save';
        if ($this->isConfigurableProduct()) {
            $action = 'saveFormHandler';
        }
        return $action;
    }

    /**
     * Is configurable product.
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function isConfigurableProduct()
    {
        return !$this->getProduct()->isComposite() || $this->getProduct()->getTypeId() === ConfigurableType::TYPE_CODE;
    }
```

Is there a way to fix that? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer.

```
return [
            'id_hard' => 'save_and_close_add',
            'label' => __('Save & Close'),
            'class' => 'save',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'buttonAdapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => $this->getSaveTarget(),
                                'actionName' => $this->getSaveAction(),
                                'params' => [
                                    true
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'class_name' => Container::DEFAULT_CONTROL,
        ];
    }
```

should include an `on_click` key with empty string.

Like that:

```
 return [
            'id_hard' => 'save_and_close_add',
            'label' => __('Save & Close'),
            'class' => 'save',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'buttonAdapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => $this->getSaveTarget(),
                                'actionName' => $this->getSaveAction(),
                                'params' => [
                                    true
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'class_name' => Container::DEFAULT_CONTROL,
            'on_click' => '',
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all, I don't think you need a `Save & Close` button. There is already one.
 [image]
But for the sake of it, let's say you want a new one.
I think the problem is the `targetName`.
For your configurable products the targetName is `product_form.product_form.configurableVariations`.
This fieldset does not contain the `form_key` hidden input so nothing gets sent as `form_key`. Hence the error message.
I see that for the default `Save & Close` button the `targetName` is `product_form.product_form`.  Maybe you should use that one also.
(See `Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Save`) for more details.

Comment: Yeah, I need a new one. Don't ask me why. In the `Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Save` there is a check for configurable product, hence `product_form.product_form.configurableVariations`. On using `product_form.product_form` with action `saveFormHandler` there is infinite redirect. On using `product_form.product_form` with action `save` the error remains

Comment: Because actually that button is defined in the `\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Save` and `product_form.xml` of `module-configurable-product`